# Should element numbering start from 0 or 1 in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, element

I'm trying to learn the concept of index and element in Java. I have seen two versions of representations for elements and am not sure which one is correct.

For an array with 4 elements, the first version assigns `Element(0)` to the first element, `Element(1)` to the second element and so on. This version is shown as the graph below.

[image]

The second version, `Element(1)` is assigned to the first element, `Element(2)` is assigned to the second element and so on.

I'm very confused as to which version of representing elements is correct and which is wrong, this is causing me a lot of confusion.

Comment: Try looking at Java's tutorials [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: For an array of four elements, the first index is zero, the last is 3 (other comments/answers already told you that).  There is **no** index 4.  If you see a text telling "first element" and "fourth element", it refers to how we normally count/enumerate items in everyday language (not to java).

Comment: but the graph I have attached shows there is index 4 (after element 3) for an array of 4 objects. lol index is giving me a massive headache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean

> Should I call `element[0]` the "zeroth" element or the "first" element?

IMO, programmers often refer to it as the first element of an array. But you can also say that it is the element at index 0.

You see what I mean? In English, `element[0]` is always the *first* element. You can look up the word "first" in a dictionary to verify this. To literally "translate" `element[0]` into English, that would be "The element at *index 0*".

Answer (score 5):

Arrays index starts from zero in java.

Comment: i know that index starts from 0, but I was asking if element numbering starts from 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

The *first* element of an array is located at index 0.

The *second* element of an array is located at index 1.

The *third* element of an array is located at index 2.

...

Basically, the *number* (as you say) of an array's element is the value of the index plus one.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by numbering. Arrays arrange data in sequential manner and we can access by an index.

In Java as others have pointed index starts from 0

What exactly are you trying to indicate by numbering ?

Comment: I want to how for the first element in an array of string, for example, should the first string be called element 1 or element 0, cause I have seen both version of numbering and is a bit confused

Comment: I any case either its array of whatever class, it starts with zero index. There is no numbering concept.

Answer (score 1):

You should start your element numbering from 0 as well. This just keeps things simple and helps avoid a lot of confusion. To elaborate further, you should just follow one nomenclature, so you dont have to remember it and dont get confused.

Answer (score 1):

I really like how Sweeper explained it. Let me add a sample piece of code to clarify a few details:

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declare an array of integers
        int[] arr;

        // allocates memory for 3 integers
        arr = new int[3];

        // initialize first element
        arr[0] = 100;
        // initialize second element
        arr[1] = 200;enter code here
        // and so forth
        arr[2] = 300;

        System.out.println("Element at index 0: "
                           + arr[0]);
        System.out.println("Element at index 1: "
                           + arr[1]);
        System.out.println("Element at index 2: "
                           + arr[2]);
    }
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
    Element at index 0: 100
    Element at index 1: 200
    Element at index 2: 300
```

For index 0, the element value is 100 and it is the 'first' element of the array. Or in other words, if you are referring to the n-th element of the array, it's index would be (n-1).

Comment: having code really helps with understanding! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome. It is nice to start with arrays to learn some programming concepts, or at places where you have predefined size of list of elements to be accessed. Soon you will find yourself graduate out of arrays and enter the domain of collections. I would recommend reading here [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm)